# char cannot be dereferenced JAVA

Tags: java

Here is my code

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class prog3{
  public static void main(String[] args){
  Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    char a1 = input.nextLine().charAt(0);
    char a = Character.toUpperCase(a1);
    String b = input.nextLine();
    int size= b.length();
    char [] arr =b.toCharArray() ;
    for (int i=0;i<size;i++){
      char temp = Character.toUpperCase(arr[i]);
   if(a==temp){
    arr[i]=arr[i].replace(a,i); // here i am facing error
     System.out.print(arr[i]);
     }


    }

  }

}
```

i am facing an error at line14

> Line:14: char cannot be dereferenced

how do i solve this

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`arr[i]` will return a `char`.  `char` is a primitive type, which cannot be dereferenced. Further, it does not have a `replace` method (or any methods for that matter).

I am not sure what you are trying to do with your code, maybe you want `arr[i]=a;`

Comment: Might be helpful to point out why. Specifically, "dereferencing" is the act of looking up which location in the heap a reference points to. A primitive isn't a reference, and thus doesn't point to any location in the heap, and thus can't be dereferenced.

Answer (score 1):

```
arr[i]=arr[i].replace(a,i);
```

1. `arr[i]` is a `char`: a primitive data type, hence can not be dereferenced.
2. `arr` is an array of `char`. An array of `char` is not a `String`. To use the `replace` function you should go for `String` or more appropriate for your case: string processing class like [`StringBuilder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html)